# How to calculate week number based on consecutive weeks spanning four years

Tags: r, dataframe, time, dplyr, lubridate

Let's say I have a set of dates stored in `df$diag`:

```
> df
        diag
1 2017-01-02
2 2017-01-02
3 2017-01-05
4 2017-01-06
5 2017-01-09
6 2017-01-18
```

I want to make a new covariate `df$week` that count consecutive weeks since monday `2017-01-02` as in `yyyy-mm-dd`, where `2017-01-02` correspond to `df$week==1`. For every monday that passes between `2017-01-02` and `2020-12-31`, the `df$week` should increase by 1.

```
> df
        diag  week
1 2017-01-02     1
2 2017-01-02     1
3 2017-01-05     1
4 2017-01-06     1
5 2017-01-09     2
6 2017-01-18     3
```

I tried

```
mutate(df, week = 1 + round(as.numeric(difftime(strptime(diag, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                                                strptime("02.01.2017", format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
                                                units="weeks"), digits = 0)))
```

Which gives

```
        diag week
1 2017-01-02    1
2 2017-01-02    1
3 2017-01-05    1
4 2017-01-06    2
5 2017-01-09    2
6 2017-01-18    3
```

However, friday the `2017-01-06` should correctly belong to `df$week==1`, while monday the `2017-01-09` should proceed to `df$week==2`.

I am looking for a solution in `dplyr`.

Data

```
df <- structure(list(diag = c("2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-05", 
"2017-01-06", "2017-01-09", "2017-01-18")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `dplyr::mutate` with `baseR`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    day_since_2017_01_02 = as.integer(difftime(diag, as.Date("2017-01-02"),
      units = "days")),
    week_index = (day_since_2017_01_02 + 1) %/% 7 + 1
  )
```

Output

```
        diag day_since_2017_01_02 week_index
1 2017-01-02                    0          1
2 2017-01-02                    0          1
3 2017-01-05                    2          1
4 2017-01-06                    3          1
5 2017-01-09                    6          2
6 2017-01-18                   15          3
```

Comment: Thank you! - the `+1` from `week_index = (day_since_2017_01_02 + 1)` had to be omitted to obtain the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

How about this (*assuming first day in diag is a monday*)

```
df %>% mutate(diag = as.Date(diag),
              weekno = as.numeric(diag - first(diag)),
              weekno = (weekno %/% 7) +1)
        diag weekno
1 2017-01-02      1
2 2017-01-02      1
3 2017-01-05      1
4 2017-01-06      1
5 2017-01-09      2
6 2017-01-18      3
```